# Show for content $\mu$ and $A_i$ disjoint: $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \subset A \Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^\infty\mu (A_i) \le \mu (A)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, summation

Let $R$ be a ring with $A\in R$ and $A_i \in R \: \:   \forall i \in \Bbb N$. Also let $\mu : R \to [ 0, \infty ]$ be a content. Now i have to show for **$A_i$ disjoint**:
$$\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \subset A \Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^\infty\mu (A_i) \le \mu (A)$$
I know that from the definition of a content $\mu (\emptyset) =0 $ and that it is **finitely additive**. I've further shown that for two sets $C, D \in R$ with $C \subset D$ it follows that $\mu (C) \le \mu(D)$. So it remains to show that $$\mu(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i )  = \sum_ {i=1}^\infty \mu(A_i)$$

How do i get from finitely additive to the above (or maybe this way is already wrong and I need a different approach to show the statement)

Any ideas or tipps? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me that countable additivity is guaranteed to hold, but fortunately it's not needed:

If $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\subset A$ then $\cup_{n=1}^NA_n\subset A$ for all $N$, hence by finite additivity
$$ \sum_{n=1}^N\mu(A_n)=\mu\Big(\bigcup_{n=1}^NA_n\Big)\leq \mu(A) $$
for all $N$. Therefore
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_n)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\mu(A_n)\leq \mu(A) $$

Comment: Ah i see, thanks a lot! You're right, on second thought i don't think either that countable additiveity follows since that would automatically make the content a premeasure.